# How to integrate Whitesource Report in to Azure Dashboards using Whitesource API's

Tags: azure, azure-devops, build-pipeline, azure-dashboard

I have a requirement to display the Whitesource report that is generated after the build pipeline in Azure dashboard's.

Is this possible? if yes can anyone guide me on what needs to be done.

Thanks

Comment: I don't think there is any ways to include white source bolt report in dashboard, you can however use 'Embeded Webpage' control in dashboard and configure to show white source bolt resource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of this time, however, it is not supported to include Whitesource Report in Azure Dashboards.